# Why would a fixture reference not be able to access a table it created in a unit test?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

So I attempted to to create a dynamodb table to run my tests with a pytest fixture like so:

```
@pytest.fixture
def db_resource():
    db_resource = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    table = db_resource.create_table(
       ...

    return db_resource
```

Then I passed it into my test like so:

```
@mock_dynamodb2
def test_my_code(db_resource):
   other_func(db_resource)
```

This throws an error saying the table I just created does not exist (this is the first time I've tried doing it this way). However if I change it to a function that generates the table it works fine.

```
@mock_dynamodb2
def _create_table():
   db_resource = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    table = db_resource.create_table(
       ...

   return db_resource
```

and call it in my unit test function...

```
@mock_dynamodb2
def test_my_code():
    db_resource = _create_table()
    other_func(db_resource)
```

This works fine. What am I missing?

Comment: I think you don't need `@mock_dynamodb2` in the fixture - this is reduntant, though I don't know if this could be a problem. If you need it in the fixture, I would try to use `with mock_dynamicdb():` inside the fixture instead of the decorator.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen I think I added that duplicate mock_dynamodb incorrectly when I was putting together my question. However, I think that is the problem. The fixture runs first then my function runs. That means that the fixture sets up the test in a real db then when the test runs it's trying to access a table that doesn't exist.